# How can I stop the Grails less-resources plugin from compiling my less files every run-app?

Tags: grails, less

Does anyone know how to get the Grails less-resources plugin to cache the compiled .css files and only re-compile if the corresponding .less file(s) have changed? It is adding a lot of time to "grails run-app".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this in the Grails mail list. The solution is to use some external tool to compile the less and add this in your version control, getting rid of the plugin and simplifying things.

Then the resources will link only for the compiled css and this will improve your startup time & memory usage.

For mac, the folks recommended [this](http://incident57.com/less/) app.

> It can be left to run in the background, and is really smart about recompiling when linked resources are updated.  It can also compress at the same time, so you end up with minified CSS files, if you choose.